# How to convert Textbox to Bytes?

Tags: c#, memory, byte, offset

I have a textbox where a user can type bytes; 0x01, 0x02, 0x03 for example.

I want the textbox text to be added in here;

```
byte[] offset = new byte[] { **TEXTBOXINPUTHERE** };
Android.SetMemory(0x0248C8FC, offset);
```

How can I accomplish this? Many examples are converting the textbox input, which I don't want.

I want a user to send a offset to a memory address. So if a user TICKS the checkbox, it inputs the textbox text that has the offset. so instead of

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[] { 0x60, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
```

I want it to be

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[] { textbox1.text };
```

User would input value like "0x01" or "0x01, 0x60, 0x00, 0x00" or any other.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. How do you want to convert text to byte array? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Is the input always in this format? I.e. single-byte hex values prefixed with `0x`, separated by a comma?

Comment: Because it's going to be much easier for the user to type `010203` than `0x01, 0x02, 0x03`

Comment: What exactly is the user typing? 0x01? 0x01,0x02? Will x0102 or xFFFFFFFF be valid as well?

Comment: Sometimes the Textbox input is 0x01 and sometimes it would be 0x60, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00. I want users to input their own offset into the code. So the byte only has to be the value from the textbox. Sounds easier then it is.

Comment: Kinda hard to explain yet it should be so easy... I want a user to send a offset to a memory address. So if a user TICKS the checkbox, it inputs the textbox text that has the offset. so instead of byte[] buffer = new byte[] { 0x60, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }; i want it to be byte[] buffer = new byte[] { textbox1.text };. User would input value like "0x01" or "0x01, 0x60, 0x00, 0x00".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you input always consists of single-byte hex values prefixed with `0x`, separated by a comma (i.e. `"0x01, 0x02, 0x03"`), then you can simply do something like:

```
var input = "0x01, 0x02, 0x03";

// no validation whatsoever
var array = input
    .Split(',')
    .Select(i => i.Trim().Replace("0x", ""))
    .Select(i => Convert.ToByte(i, 16))
    .ToArray();
```

Or, a slightly less strict version would split on different separator characters (e.g. commas, spaces, tabs):

```
private static byte[] GetByteArrayFromHexString(string input)
{
    return input
        .Split(new[] { ',',' ','\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(i => i.Trim().Replace("0x", ""))
        .Select(i => Convert.ToByte(i, 16))
        .ToArray();
}
```

This should work for several different inputs, so that your users don't have to type all that unnecessary stuff:

```
// all these variants produce the same output
GetByteArrayFromHexString("0x01, 0x02, 0x03")  // --> new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 }
GetByteArrayFromHexString("0x01 0x02 0x03")    // --> new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 }
GetByteArrayFromHexString("01 02 03")          // --> new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 }
```

Comment: @user3206153: Great. You might also consider allowing users to use spaces instead of commas, like in the second example. If I used such a program, I would probably prefer to simply write `01 02 03`, instead of `0x01, 0x02, 0x03`.